# redirect ALL traffic to https. NGINX

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect all traffic to https://example.com no matter what the user types in.

The following .conf file is very close but it does not catch http://example.com

what would you suggest that I change in order for ALL traffic to redirect to https://example.com ?

Thank you.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
   server_name example.com;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;
   root /var/www/html/web;

   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
   }

   rewrite ^/backend\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location /admin {
        index admin content backend.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /backend.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another server record for `http://example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Also, make sure that the main server-record only listens on port `443`, so add this to it:

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

Comment: kills the site completely. and it complains that there is a duplicate server_name

Comment: sorry it doesn't complain but it takes the site down completely.

Comment: What does `sudo nginx -t` output?

Comment: Oh, and you might need to add ssl to all the 443-listens: `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: i will have to try this in non production. I am not sure if it matters but it is in AWS Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate server blocks.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com
                example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
   server_name example.com;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;
   root /var/www/html/web;

   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
   }

   rewrite ^/backend\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location /admin {
        index admin content backend.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /backend.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```